# SQL Server cannot subscribe to or be subscribed remotely to a Replication Publication?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, replication

I have a main SQL Server, running SQLServer 2000, with two (in theory) subscribing servers, each running SQL Server 2005.

One of these is subscribing fine, but the other always seems to fail subscribing, both when attempting to set up the subscription from the publisher (SQL2000) to the subscriber(SQL2005), and when trying to set it up from the subscriber to the publisher, both via Server Management Studio 2008 and via SQL Enterprise Manager

In both cases, the publication is created on the publisher, but a corresponding subscription is not created on the subscriber.

I then get an error message saying "The process could not connect to Subscriber [ServerName]", and no more sign of activity. There's no problem with logins, permissions, etc. The password for sa is the same on both machines, and is different on the 2005 machine that works.

Is this a problem anyone else has encountered?

EDIT: I've now tried adding both a dbSubscriber and a dbPublisher access account on each server so that they're not logging into each other using "sa", but it doesn't seem to have made any difference.

EDIT2: Adding a push subscription does not create a Local Subscription on the subscribing server. Is this normal, or is this the point at which everything is falling to pieces?

Comment: I suggest that you script out the Replication Configuration scripts, prior to actually running them via SSMS, so that you can see "exactly" what is/is not being performed.

Comment: There's a single message being sent out to the publisher to establish the publisher/subscriber connection. I have no idea whether that's normal or not.

Comment: When creating a Push subscription, there's a single message being sent out to the publisher to establish the publisher/subscriber connection. When creating a Pull subscription, there's one message to the publisher and two to the pulling Subscriber. I have no idea whether that's normal or not.

Comment: Are the server able to talk to each other? If you login on one of the server can you connect to the other one directly and vice versa.

Comment: @jfrobishow: Yes, I can connect to each server. In addition, the transmission of the Snapshot always reports that it has been delivered successfully. It's only after the snapshot is delivered that the connection fails.

Comment: Have you validated that the SQL Server Agents used by Replication are using valid credentials with sufficient access rights?

Comment: @John Sansom: Sorry, didn't expand to see your comment. I've tried with the sa user on both servers, and also using, on each, pulling and pushing, an all-permissions user I created for the purpose of replication, with every permission tickbox ticked except denyread and denywrite. No dice.

Comment: What are the differences between the two subscribing servers? (e.g. network, OS, service pack etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't really understand what was going wrong, but we *think* that the 2005 server was unable to accept the 2000 server as a Push Publisher.

We created four different Pull subscriptions on the 2005 server and the first three failed, while the fourth magically worked.

We are accepting this as a blessing from the God of Computers and will not question His benevolence.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for posting an update, always good to know how things turned out.

There are "complications" and intracacies involved when creating SQL Server Replication topologies incorporating different versions of SQL Server, as it sounds like you are discovering.

Keep in mind that Replication functionality is limited to that of the oldest version of SQL Server in your topology:

[Using Multiple Versions of SQL Server in a Replication Topology](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143241.aspx)